# microservices eureka server docker image dockercompose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, devops, netflix-eureka

i have problem with docker eureka-server image
[image]

this is my code discovery on post 8761

and this is my docker compose code :

discovery:

```
build: C:\Users\Asus\Documents\github\microservice\Spring-Boot---Eureka-Server
ports:
  - "8761:8761" 
image: "kirox2023**/eureka"
```

i have eureka clients and eureka server

[image: i have eureka clients and eureka server]

All eureka clients working without problem only eureka server

[image: not working]

[image: inaccessible]